# Is there a command similar to docker exec in lando?

Tags: lando

We are using our develpment environment in a lando and non lando context alike. Is there a way to trigger a shell script from outside lando similar to `docker exec` ?

`lando exec` does not work obvisously and it is also not part of the standard commands, but maybe tehre is a way to create it or add it as a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out, that lando has this build in as part of the [tooling api](https://docs.lando.dev/config/tooling.html#usage). It does not allow a "freestyle" command, but you can predefine any usefull shortcut you like in the `.lando.yml`.

A simple example in our case:

```yaml
name: my_project
recipe: drupal9
config:
  database: mariadb
  drush: ^10
  php: '7.4'
  webroot: ./web
tooling:
  cex:
    service: appserver
    description: Export the drupal config
    cmd: './scripts/cex.sh'
  cim:
    service: appserver
    description: Install dependencies and import the latest config.
    cmd: './scripts/cim.sh'
```

If you need root permissions, just add `user: root`

In the example above, you can simply call

`lando cex` or `lando cim`, to trigger the custom commands.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a better way to execute one time commands than using the tooling API, that is also more similar to docker exec:

```bash
# Opens an interactive terminal inside container
lando ssh

# Runs a specified command inside container
lando ssh -c "ls -la /"
```

You can change the target service/container and the executing user which runs the command:

```
  --command, -c   Run a command in the service
  --service, -s   SSH into this service [default: "appserver"]
  --user, -u      Run as a specific user
```

See full documentation for `lando ssh` here:
https://docs.lando.dev/basics/ssh.html#usage